# apache, mod_reqtimeout and Keep-Alive

Tags: python, apache, http

I am trying to test an Apache module. I'm using a python script that opens an HTTP connection and sends several thousand json packets at the server. Each packet is an individual request. The problem is that I believe I'm getting a stack overflow in apache that's obviously causing it to crash. Here's the gdb output:

```
#0  0x00007ffff7ffb8d4 in gettimeofday ()
#1  0x00007ffff776fa58 in apr_time_now () from /usr/lib/libapr-1.so.0
#2  0x00007ffff56dcaed in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mod_reqtimeout.so
#3  0x00007ffff56dcd84 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mod_reqtimeout.so
#4  0x00007ffff56dcd84 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mod_reqtimeout.so
#5  0x00007ffff56dcd84 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mod_reqtimeout.so
#6  0x00007ffff56dcd84 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mod_reqtimeout.so
#7  0x00007ffff56dcd84 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mod_reqtimeout.so
#8  0x00007ffff56dcd84 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mod_reqtimeout.so
#9  0x00007ffff56dcd84 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mod_reqtimeout.so
#10 0x00007ffff56dcd84 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mod_reqtimeout.so
...
#43661 0x00007ffff56dcd84 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mod_reqtimeout.so
#43662 0x00007ffff56dcd84 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mod_reqtimeout.so
#43663 0x000000000045c68d in ap_http_filter ()
#43664 0x00007ffff3c9cc82 in apreq_filter_prefetch () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mod_apreq2.so
#43665 0x00007ffff3c9ba33 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mod_apreq2.so
#43666 0x00007ffff3a92b4b in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapreq2.so.3
#43667 0x00007ffff3a92b8e in apreq_param () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapreq2.so.3
#43668 0x00007ffff36672e3 in rtb_handler (r=0x7fff7045f0a0) at /home/james/mymodule.cpp:550
#43669 0x00000000004479a8 in ap_run_handler ()
#43670 0x0000000000447dfe in ap_invoke_handler ()
#43671 0x000000000045b60a in ap_process_async_request ()
#43672 0x0000000000458437 in ?? ()
#43673 0x0000000000450b28 in ap_run_process_connection ()
#43674 0x000000000046307b in ?? ()
#43675 0x00007ffff776f417 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libapr-1.so.0
#43676 0x00007ffff752be9a in start_thread (arg=0x7fff557d2700) at pthread_create.c:308
#43677 0x00007ffff7258ccd in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:112
#43678 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

Line 550 of mymodule.cpp is in the handler:

```
apreq_handle_t *req = apreq_handle_apache2(r);
```

The number of frames is suspiciously close to the number of packets I send before the SIGSEGV occurs.

The python script is essentially:

```
def main():
   conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("127.0.0.1", 8080)
   headers = {
       "Content-type": "application/json",
       "Accept": "text/plain",
       "Connection": "keep-alive"
   }

   with open("logfile.txt") as f:
       packets = f.readlines()

       for packet in packets:
           conn.request("POST", "/url", packet, headers)
           response = conn.getresponse()
           data = response.read()

   conn.close()
```

In the module the time taken to parse the request body increases linearly yet I cannot find any recursion in our code. So I'm stuck. Maybe the mod_reqtimeout module is incompatible with Keep-Alive connections, or there's something wrong with my test script?

Edit: Just removing mod_reqtimeout from httpd.conf seems to resolve the issue. Another one I'm facing is that if the test script is killed, apache also receives SIGHUP. How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: You do have an indentation issue after `with open("logfile.txt") as f:`, but that should not be the source of your problem.

Comment: @cwallenpoole Yes, that's just from the copy & paste from the code to stackoverflow. I'll fix it.

Comment: I assumed as much, but it never hurts to mention these things.

Comment: Did you try something like `ab -n 10000 -c 10 -p foo.txt -T "application/json" http://your-apache-server.com` where `foo.txt` is sonething like `{'name':'Bob', 'position':'hacker'}`

Comment: @Vor I did not, in reality my test script actually generates the json on the fly from info in the log.txt. I jst kept it simple for the sake of this question. But that's a very nice command, thanks for that. It will be used! EDIT: That seems to try to post the entire file, not each line in the file!